# Firebase Authentication : how to get current user's Password?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i'm new to **firebase Authentication**.. so, i'm creating a basic app with a profile, i've made an activity to edit basic informations of the user such as `DisplayName` and `Email`... , i wan't to add the capability of changing passwords, but first , i wan't to check current user's password and compare it to a `String` from an `InputEditText` that the user must know his current password before changing it.

EDIT : 
the thing i'm asking about is i ask the user to write his current `Password` in order to be able to change it to a new one to reduce hacking or something like that, like on `Facebook` when you're trying to change the `Email` or `Password` or even the `Name` it asks you for your current `Password`.

[image: ![Example]

Comment: This is way too broad you need to show an example of what you mean and what you are currently trying

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with Firebase?  Are you using Firebase Authentication?

Comment: i ask the user to write his current password in order to be able to change it to a new one to reduce hacking or something like that, like on facebook when you're trying to change the email or password or even the name it asks you for your current password.

Comment: okay you really need to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and expalin your question better

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: If you read the firebase docs there is a method in there to change a users password, and check if a user is signed in, and how to sign a user in etc if this is what you mean https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: i've seen those docs , but the thing i want , before appliying these methods to change the password, i want to check if the user is the account owner , so no one can change your password even if he finds your account logged in he must know the old password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user):

> Some security-sensitive actions—such as deleting an account, setting a primary email address, and [changing a password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_password)—require that the user has recently signed in.
>
> If you perform one of these actions, and the user signed in too long ago, the action fails and throws `FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException`. When this happens, re-authenticate the user by getting new sign-in credentials from the user and passing the credentials to reauthenticate. For example:
>
> ```
> FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
>
> // Get auth credentials from the user for re-authentication. The example below shows
> // email and password credentials but there are multiple possible providers,
> // such as GoogleAuthProvider or FacebookAuthProvider.
> AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
>     .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");
> // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
> user.reauthenticate(credential)
>     .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
>         @Override
>         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
>             Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: so when the user tries to change the password, this method askes him to reSign in ? please i don't really get it.

Comment: Changing the password requires that the user has recently signed in. If it's been too long since they last signed in, Firebase will throw an exception. When that happens, you need to reauthenticate before trying to change the password again.

Comment: Hey Tamim, this is the mechanism where you first ask the user to provide their existing password first. You re-authenticate with that. If successful, you then can ask the user for the new password and call `updatePassword` API to update the user's password. It is exactly what you are asking for.